# Phonegap 3.6 iOS plugin not found

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I know there are many topics handle this problem. But so far I was not able to understand why my own plugins are not getting called.

First of all:

- I use phonegap 3.6.3, XCode 6.1, iOS 8.1 Beta
- I am upgrading phonegap 2.9.0 to 3.6.3 with CLI. In 2.9.0 my Plugin 'Notification' worked just fine.
- I read about upgrading from 2.x to 3.x and did all the stuff mentioned.
- I added core plugins with CLI which (almost) all are working.
- I read about adding plugins with CLI, but I don't have a git source, and I just want to put this plugin into xCode so that I can call it from js as CDVPlugin just as before in 2.9.0

My config.xml (in myApp/ folder) looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="ch.itis.share" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <feature name="com.popup.test.plugins.Notification" required="true">
        <param name="ios-package" value="Notification" />
    </feature>

</widget
```

I have my Notification.h and Notifiaction.m class files inside myApp/Plugins folder and added them to the Build Phase in XCode.

I executed the command 'cordova prepare' to update the staging folder.

The staging config.xml has never the  defined obove included!

When I call the plugin from js like:

```
Cordova.exec(
  function(result){//do something},
  function(error){//do something},
  "com.popup.test.plugins.Notification",
  "initDeviceNotification",
  []);
```

All I get from Phonegap is:

> Plugin 'com.popup.test.plugins.Notification' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

I have many plugins like that. And nothing works anymore. Can anybody help?

**UPDATE:**

If I add the  section manually to the staging config.xml it works. So how can I accomplish that the CLI prepare command will include my feature?

Comment: I can't find the plugin on http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=notification

Comment: That's exactly the problem. It is not a public plugin. I wrote it myself and I need it in the config.xml. But the config.xml gets overwritten everytime I execute "corodva prepare"

Comment: And you build our plugin according to the documentation (plugman compatible?): http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: You mean instead of using 'cordova add' I shall use 'plugman install'? ok, maybe this is an option. But I have no myplugin.js.. my plugin.js is included in a compressed app.js. So if this is a problem, it won't work.

Comment: It looks like the feature tag from the top level config.xml is explicitly not merged into the platform specific config.xml. See https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/57f454b2875fd429d1b02da5bd5c3196d77363e6/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js#L129

Comment: Thx @bit
Is there a common way to force those top level features into merge? maybe another tag? I came up to the solution to copy those features manually into stage/config.xml everytime after prepare.